# Dynamic Component Presentation indexing using DXA Search module (SI4T)

Tags: web8, dxa, si4t

I have installed DXA Search module for indexing data in SOLR. Pages are indexing properly in SOLR.

Now my requirement is to publish Dynamic Component Presentations with custom fields, and those custom fields data should be indexed in SOLR.

I am also looking how we can map one to one Schema fields with SOLR fields.

Any pointer and guidelines will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the same activity in one of my project. You need to add the Enable Search Indexing TBB on your dynamic CT. 
Also if you wants to have your own custom fields to add in SOLR.

1. Update the `SearchIndexCustomFieldMap` parameters of Enable Search Indexing
2. Add fields in SOLR `managed-schema.xml` file

The format of the map definition is as follows:

```
indexFieldA:field1,field2|indexFieldB:field3|indexFieldC+:field4,field5
```

You can also refer the below link -What-Gets-Indexed

https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki/Configuring-Templates-:-What-Gets-Indexed%3F

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. It really helped me a lot.